# Is there a way to use format strings to partition a string?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string "123456". It's a number, we can convert it too if that helps.
I want to use a format string to get "456" out. Is that possible? Sort of like Substring(3,6) only with a format string.

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0c899ak8(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: This is not formatting. This is getting substring as you said.

Comment: You can use Regex with Groups in it... That's a kind of format string

Comment: A format string is usually used to "format" a string. Do you "just" want to get specific parts of the string? In this case there are several ways. It is not really clear what are you trying to do - please be a little more specific.

Comment: You'll have to be clearer I'm afraid. By what logic should 456 be 'partitioned' from the original string? Do you want to be left with 2 strings (`"123"` and `"456"`)? Or just extract 456? Are there an arbitrary amount of 'partitions'? And more importantly, what is the preference to use `String.Format` as opposed to `Substring` based on?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, but personally I'd rather use a substring directly.

The following code probably doesn't cover the edge cases but illustrates the point:

```
    public sealed class SubstringFormatter : ICustomFormatter, IFormatProvider
{
    private readonly static Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\d+),(\d+)", RegexOptions.Compiled);


    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        Match match = regex.Match(format);

        if (!match.Success)
        {
            throw new FormatException("The format is not recognized: " + format);
        }

        if (arg == null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        int startIndex = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
        int length = int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value);

        return arg.ToString().Substring(startIndex, length);
    }

    public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        return formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter) ? this : null;
    }
}
```

To call it:

```
    var formatter = new SubstringFormatter();

    Console.WriteLine(string.Format(formatter, "{0:0,4}", "Hello"));
```

The output to this would be "Hell"